# No module named 'ecommerce.store' in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I run command **python3 manage.py runserver** It throws an error showing that no module named ecommerce.store but it is.

This is my ecommerce.store.views file

```
    from ecommerce.store.models import Product
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *  

def store(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

def cart(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)

def checkout(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)
```

This is my ecommerce.store.admin file

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register(Customer)
admin.site.register(Product)
admin.site.register(Order)
admin.site.register(OrderItem)
admin.site.register(ShippingAddress)
```

This is my ecommerce.store.models file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignKey

class Customer(models.Model) :
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model) :
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self) :
        return str(self.id)

class OrderItem(models.Model) :
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class ShippingAddress(models.Model) :
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str_(self):
        return self.address
```

This is my ecommerce.store.urls file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.store, name="store"),
    path('cart/', views.cart, name="cart"),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name="checkout"),
]
```

This is the image of the actual error showing in terminal please help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPgyw.jpg)

Thanks for helping me

Comment: "showing that no module named ecommerce.store but it is." In your own words, why do you think there should be one? If it is supposed to be from your code, then you should a) show your *folder hierarchy*;  b) make sure you understand how the import system works (especially relative imports). If it is supposed to be from something you installed, then you need to explain about that. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

`from ecommerce.store.models import Product` will find package `ecommerce` from project root dir, this will find the subdirectory `ecommerce` not root directory `ecommerce`, you can use absolute import:

```py
from store.models import Product
```

or just use relative import(recommended way):

```py
from .models import Product
```

Comment: I have modified the relative import, you can try it `from .models import Product`

Answer (score 0):

try change your wrong import:

```
from ecommerce.models import Product
```

Comment: u made all migrations?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, found out that I did not import the forms into views.py header file.

Check to make sure that this has been imported

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).